# Package android.os does not exist (when compiling with JDK 11)

Tags: java, android, gradle, intellij-idea

I have started an Android app using Intellij and Gradle. At some point I got the following error message:

```
error: package android.os does not exist
import android.os.StrictMode;
```

I have noticed that it works fine when I use JDK 1_8 but fails when I use JDK 11. Does anyone know how to fix this?

It works with:

```
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
```

It fails with:

```
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
}
```

Comment: as far as I know, the max you can use is 1_8

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue. Did you figure out how to fix it? @Alex de Kruijff

Comment: @AdrianaPineda Yes, go back to 1_8.

Answer (score 0):

Issue is still present.

I don't see a reason to revert back to 1_8 because it is outdated.
Even Java 11 is LTS for a limited remaining timespan (The new LTS is soon to be released)

11 seems to be supported (https://www.mobileit.cz/Blog/Pages/android-java-release-train.aspx)

Comment: Soon == in ~6 months time, if Oracle sticks to the release schedule. And Java 11 LTS will be on Premium support until Sept 2023.  So calling "time" on Java 11 LTS is premature.